# yii2 pagination error not showing all the data in the tables

Tags: php, angularjs, yii, pagination, yii2

sorry but I have been looking for the answer to this question but I haven't found it yet.

we have this project Yii2 and AngularJS. The problem is that Yii only returns 20 items from the table. I went to the vendor and founded the pagination file I modified this lines:

```
public $defaultPageSize = 20;
public $pageSizeLimit = [1, 50];
```

to

```
public $defaultPageSize = 0;
public $pageSizeLimit = [0, 50];
```

And that's the only way it shows all the data on the tables but I need to do that in a file outside the vendor files.

How can I do that?
What files do I need to modify?

I have tried in the config but it doesn't work. I have to set that globally because in all the data that we display I have the same problem.

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is  disable the pagination  .. .  setting pagination  to false eg:  tif you are creating a dataProvider you can

```
return new ActiveDataProvider([
   'pagination' => false,
]);
```

or in the model related to your problem you can set the pagination

Comment: thanks for replying. I don't know where to create the data provider so it can be applied to all the forms in the app because it has Angularjs. How can I set the pagination in the models?

Comment: typically the dataProvider for an activeRecord is create in modelSearch ..(if you use gii for create the code scaffolding for an activeRecord)  -- so you can replace the pagination, for the model you need  in the search function of modelSeach

Comment: I tried in the model but it doesn´t work. how can i globally do it? I have at least 35 forms. is it be possible to do it in the params of the app, if so how?

Comment: Have you a modelSearch related  to this model?

Comment: @Andrs888 You should not use a global setting for this, you should find the dataProviders in all the searchModels related and make this change. It is the default way to do this and a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

[@scaisEdge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40874033/428543) is correct and in my opinion is the best way to go to avoid accidentally querying a really large dataset.

However, you can use [dependency injection](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-di-container.html) to set the initial value for pagination. In your entry script add:

```
\Yii::$container->set('yii\data\ActiveDataProvider', ['pagination' => false]);
```

Please note that it is being set in the data provider `yii\data\ActiveDataProvider` and not `yii\data\Pagination` as setting it in pagination will affect everything that uses pagination.